# Why is text written after a table tag in HTML source displaying before the table?

Tags: php, html

I wrote this code, but I faced a problem: when I run the code it shows me the result in the incorrect order.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
{
    die("not ok");
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  

$q1 = "SELECT * FROM student_record INNER JOIN degree_plan ON
 student_record.course_number = degree_plan.course_number 
 INNER JOIN courses ON student_record.course_number = 
 courses.course_number where student_record.id = 201102887 AND degree_plan.major='COE';";

$result = mysqli_query($con , $q1 ) ;
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
    $data[$row["term_no"]][] =  array(
        'code' => $row["code"],
        'grade' => $row["grade"],
        'crd' => $row["crd"]
    );

}


   echo '<table>';
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>courses</th>";
   echo "<th>terms</th>";
   echo "<th>grades</th>";
   echo "<th>CRD</th>";
   echo "</tr>";

foreach($data as $term=>$otherrow) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($otherrow as $row) {
        if($count == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
            echo '<td rowspan="'.count($otherrow).'">' . $term. '</td>';
            echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["crd"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

        else 

        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["crd"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $count++;
    }
}

echo "Hello";


?>
```

I wrote in the last of the code `echo "Hello";` but when I run it, it displays `Hello` above the table, like this:

```
Hello
table
```

How I can make the the code first echo the table, then echo Hello?
like this

```
table
hello
```

Comment: I think a closing `</table>` tag might help.

Comment: yes, it help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<table>` tag is not closed. In most browsers, this error will cause subsequent text to display before the table rows. This is why you are seeing `"Hello"` before your table content.

You can verify this by viewing the page source in your browser. The `Hello` *will* actually be after the table rows in the source, even though it shows up before them when the browser renders the source. In Firefox, the invalid HTML (`<table>` with no closing tag, invalid text inside a table) will be highlighted in red.